# AsyncPostBackTrigger in nested repeater

Tags: asp.net

Good day everyone,

This is my first post in here and I would like to thank you all for the great efforts in this forum by which I have already gaind a lot of skills.

I have a smalle issue with two nested repeaters. Basically, I have a dropdownlist in a child repeater which contains rating values and every time the dropdownlist is changed in the child repeater the new percentange is calculated and presented in a label in the parent repeater. This will cause full postback which is really frustrating when going through too many dropdownlists. My question is how to reflect the new calculated percentange in the label without postback. I have tried to use AsyncPostBackTriggers but no luck. Any suggestions would be appreiciated

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptParent" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblAvg" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TrialScore")%>'></asp:Label>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptChild" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="lstRate" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lstRate_SelectedIndexChanged" />

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Have you considered using UpdatePanels from Ajax Control Toolkit?

Comment: Yes, I did. However, myabe I didn't use it the right way. If you can tell me the right method, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your aspx mark up inside update panel like this.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="sever" ID="upParentChild" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptParent" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblAvg" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TrialScore")%>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptChild" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="lstRate" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lstRate_SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>        
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This will make sure that only controls inside update panel are posted back and not the whole page.

Comment: I am sorry for my belated reply. Honestly, I have tried your code before but it didn't work. In my case, I want to completely avoid postback. I just want to change the lable value in the parent repeater when the selectedindexchanged for the dropdownlist in child repeater (without postback at all). I have tried to use AsyncPostBackTrigger as shown below but it didnt work `</ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lstRate" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /></Triggers>`. I get error message control lstRate couldn't be found for updatepanel.

Comment: Have you tried without using `AsyncPostBackTrigger`? If you put any server control inside an update panel it will be updated asynchronously and would do a `Callback` instead of a `Postback`. It does not necessarily require an `AsyncPostBackTrigger`.

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi What you are saying is not true for nested controls.